# How can I alphabetize a C# class with Resharper 2017?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm trying to add a bit of organization to some growing files and am having limited success.  I want to alphabetize all the code files in my project, but I'm only able to get the alphabetization on my controllers, which works great, but I'd like to organize factories, etc... by alpha too.  I run the full code cleanup for those and it applies style rules, but doesn't reorder by alpha.  Is there something else I need to do?  I already edited my file layout like so:

[image: Resharper Layout Screenshot]